# changing attribute of a html div tag from asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following `<div>` in my html page and I want to change its Data-To attribute value from code behind in asp.net

```
<div id="camp" class="number count-to" data-from="0" data-to="125" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
```

I have a JavaScript function that sets the value but I'm not able to set its value from code behind in asp.net; my JavaScript function is following...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function myfunc() {
            $('#camp').countTo({ from: 0, to: 100 });
        }
         my func();
</script>
```

I want to call my func from asp.net.

Comment: what do you mean want to call myFun from code behind? What is the event that you want to trigger it?

Comment: i want to call it after page has loaded

Comment: PS: is there any way to change the value of data-to attribute of the division directly without javascript. that would solve my problem too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="camp" class="number count-to" data-from="<%= SomeFromValue %>" data-to="<%= SomeToValue%>" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
```

Alternatively give it a `runat="server"` and set it from code behind:

```
<div runat=server id="camp" class="number count-to" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"></div>
```

Somewhere in code behind:

```
 camp.Attributes.Add("data-to", "10");
 camp.Attributes.Add("data-from", "1");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.

It was because my `<div>` tag was inside the `<form>` tag..

Asp.net calls javascript codes when it finds `<from>` tag.
I put my div tag before `<form>` tag and it's working.. :)